# What's the right way to append a ToolButton to a Toolbar in Gtk?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, toolbar, gtk#

Monodoc tells me "AppendItem" is deprecated, but it doesn't tell me what to use instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Gtk+](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkToolbar.html#gtk-toolbar-insert) documentation. Do you have an "insert" function available?

Edit: add code sample from jpobst

```
myToolBar.Insert (myToolItem, myToolBar.NItems);
```

Comment: And yes, I realize that you're using C#, and I pointed to the C docs

Comment: I do have the insert function available, but I'd rather just append the buttons, so that I don't have to worry about indices.

Comment: myToolBar.Insert (myToolItem, myToolBar.NItems);